# phpmailer issue. Unable to get rid of the smtp connect() error

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a mail using phpmailer but getting this error "SMTP connect() failed". I've already allowed less secure apps on gmail. Is all the smtp setting correct? Please guide me where I'm wrong.

```
  <?php

   require_once 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  require 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';
   require 'PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->username = 'mymail@gmail.com';
        $mail->password = 'mypassword';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPDebug = true;

        $mail->isHTML();

        $mail->Subject = 'form data';
        $mail->Body = 'this is the body of message';

        $mail->FromName = 'The Form';

        $mail->AddAddress('junaidshekh21@gmail.com','Junaid Shaikh');


        if($mail->send())
        {
            echo "sent successfully";
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "could not send";
        }

?>
```

Comment: The error says all, it can't connect to given credentials. 587 port is sometimes blocked by the hosting provider. This might be the issue.

Comment: I'm trying this on localhost. What should i do?

Comment: Try what Pedro wrote.

Comment: already tried that. Still no luck. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Use `ErrorInfo` in `phpmail` to see what's wrong

add this before sending the email

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  //enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
```

and change from

```
echo "could not send";
```

to

```
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Read the phpmail troubleshooting, specifically the part that talks
   about ["SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)
2. Use the official [gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) from the phpmailer github repo.
3. You may have to [allow less secure apps to access your gmail
   account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)
4. Your ip may be blocked by google.

---

**UPDATE:**

From the official `phpmailer` gmail example:

```
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
```

Comment: $mail->ErrorInfo; gives the error smtp connect() failed. And I've already allowed less secure apps on gmail

Comment: Did you try using the gmail example provided on the phpmailer github repo ? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Comment: hey pedro, after doing what u suggested in your last update, I'm getting this output.... http://imgur.com/5pk1Nry

Comment: I can read in the middle of tons of debug: "Username and password not accepted " and after that, there's a link to a google answer. Can you please post it here as a comment .

Comment: what do I need to post?

Comment: the link to the google answer that's inside the debug log.

Comment: I'm sure your answer is there :)

Answer (score 1):

Your PHPmailer settings are ok i think it was less secure app access problem. 
you must make your gmail to less secure  to get access.
got to this url https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
to access your gmail as SMTP.

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and mine ?

Comment: @Pedro Lobito i didn't see that line  bellow sorry for that

Comment: @Jkumar, that's ok, no problem, just want to keep SO clean for everyone !

Comment: @JunaidShaikh can you paste error code or error message so we can help

Comment: junaid, put ur above comment as note in ur question. I'm not on my pc so can't do much help. the code is fine. Will try to reply when get home.

Comment: This is the output I'm getting.....  "SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"

Comment: @JunaidShaikh check if you have openssl extension loaded  or not if not then enable it from php.ini and make host to ssl://smtp.gmail.com